# Wordpress Trim Words in Content in Posts Archive With HTML Formatting

Tags: html, wordpress, formatting, trim

I'm trying to limit the number of Words in a repeating posts/posts archive. However, when I trim the words WordPress seems to remove all the formatting - the word limit works fine. Here is what I have so far:

```
 <?php
// trim the content
global $post;
 $my_content= $post->post_content;
 //$my_content = get_the_content();
 trimmed_my_content = wp_trim_words( $my_content, 400, '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'">&nbsp;<span class="moretext">More</span></a>' );
//echo $trimmed_my_content;
echo apply_filters('trimmed_my_content', $trimmed_my_content);
?>
```

You will see from the // out PHP that I have tried a couple of approaches with no success. However, if I just output the content in the loop with no filtering it works fine:

```
 <?php the_content('Read more...'); ?>
```

Works with HTML filtering/formatting.

I should note I want to include this code in my WordPress template as I am limiting the content/excerpt elsewhere and I don't want it to be universal. Obviously, a function in functions.php called by PHP in the template is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$my_content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
```

Instead of:

```
$my_content = $post->post_content;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that still outputs one block of unformatted text. I did note a missing '$' on the 6th line of my code, but that was lost in submission and not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
     global $post;
     //$my_content= $post->post_content;
     $my_content=apply_filters('the_content',$post->post_content);//this will get the content for you

     trimmed_my_content = wp_trim_words( $my_content, 400, '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'">&nbsp;<span class="moretext">More</span></a>' );
    echo $trimmed_my_content;
    ?>
```

Or you can now format your data as required.